# When can I access the DLC content?

Tags: dead-island

I Got the 2 DLC(Ryder White and Bloodbath Arena) for dead island,but when are they available for me to play?

Do I have to complete the game or get to a specific locations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All new blueprints and weapons are added to your game with the install of the DLC.

### Ryder White

According to [the Dead Island Wiki](http://deadislandwiki.com/wiki/Ryder_White%27s_Campaign), this DLC was released on February 1, 2012.

As you can clearly see in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VD0ADYAADg#t=1m22s), **you can access this content by selecting Ryder White at the character select screen at the start of a new campaign.**

### Bloodbath Arena

Bloodbath Arena as described on [the Dead Island Wiki](http://deadislandwiki.com/wiki/Bloodbath_Arena) states:

> ...the DLC was available for download on November 22, 2011
>
> **The arena is accessed from the resort jungle tunnel entrance**, there is a door labeled "Arena Entrance" at the mouth of the tunnel. After entering for the first time, it is then found on the Fast Travel screen.

Comment: oh I missed to notice ryder on selection screen -_-